# Transform a list including a dictionary into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

First I have a list like this:

```
lst = [['amazon', {'param_A': '789', 'param_B': '1234'}]]`
```

The first element always represents a shop.

I want to transform this list into a dataframe.

I think the easiest way to do this, would be to create a dictionary:

```
dicts={'shop':['amazon'],'param_A': ['789'], 'param_B': ['1234']}
```

Next step is: `pd.DataFrame(dicts)`

This way I get a dataframe where the keys of the dict are the column names.

[image]

How do I create a dictionary? Do you know a better way?

Comment: maybe provide and exampe with a few entries and then it will be easier to give you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create list of dictionaries first and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
lst = [['amazon', {'param_A': '789', 'param_B': '1234'}],
       ['amazon', {'param_A': '22', 'param_B': '1234'}]]

L = [{**{'shop': x[0]}, **x[1]} for x in lst]
#similar solution
L = [dict(shop=x[0], **x[1]) for x in lst]

df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df)
     shop param_A param_B
0  amazon     789    1234
1  amazon      22    1234
```